# No internet access when using a PPTP VPN server

Tags: vpn, dhcp, pptp, dd-wrt

I've followed the tutorial on this site: http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?t=132029

I have a DD-WRT router with Micro-FW that does not have a built-in VPN server. I have port forwarded the port 1723 TCP to my Ubuntu box. My DD-WRT router's DHCP ranges from 192.168.1.100 - 199.

The problem is that I can connect to my VPN server and access all the network shares and computers but I cannot access the internet. I am not too sure why this is happening. Please let me know if you want to see any of the files.

I have set the `/etc/pptpd.conf`:

```
localip 192.168.1.102
remoteip 192.168.1.190-198
```

Do I need to manage my DHCP on my Ubuntu box as well or is that okay? I am a beginner, any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have the exact same problem, please let me know if you've found a solution! :) Though, Ive allready added netmask "255.255.255.0" via "/etc/ppp/options"... But I can't seem to find a way to pass the gateway to the client.

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version?  What router hardware (brand, model), and release of **DD-WRT** ?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the options file with `sudo nano /etc/ppp/pptpd-options`

uncomment the line that reads `#ms-dns 10.0.0.1` by removing the `#`

Replace the address with whatever DNS server you wish to use
`Save` and `exit`

Restart the pptp service with `sudo /etc/init.d/pptpd restart`